# How to make Text views and Toggle buttons in a single scroll view in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I have 40 Toggle Buttons in my program,and i want to add 40 text views for each button. I need to make my TextView and Toggle button scrollable .How can i do that? Can anybody help me plz??

Answer (score 0):

In your xml add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Here you put the rest of your current view...Any layout can be placed within the scrollview and this will be scrollable-->

</ScrollView>
```